# Container not reachable under Docker Desktop

Tags: angular, docker-desktop

i have the following issue:

I'm using Docker Desktop on a Windows 10 Machine. I'm trying to run an angular website inside a container and access this website from the hosts browser.

But currently, exactly this won't happen.
When i try to open the website with firefox, i only get a "Connection interrupted".

I'm already forewarding a port via

`docker run -p 4200:4200 angular-website:latest`

and tried several other tips from the internet, but none would work.

Thanks for your help!

PS: I'm running the container from my home computer. So there should be no Firealls or whatsoever.

Comment: can you share (docker ps -a) result?

Comment: @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili 
`e7fa23fc28ae, angular-website:latest, "ng serve", 2 hours ago, Up 30 seconds, 0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp, clever_napier`

Comment: I didn't specifie a container name and so docker named it "clever_napier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two solutions for this.
1 - write this in your Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 4200
```

2 - build your image with this command or write this in your Dockerfile cmd command:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: This worked for me. Just one question: Why is "--host 0.0.0.0" needed in this context?

Comment: You should use 0.0.0.0 as the ip to host it for anyone on your network to talk to. without this you can connect only with your host (In this case, host is your docker container). This means that you can only connect to the served project inside the container

Answer (score 0):

In your docker file

```
#First stage
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build --prod

#Second stage
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
    
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/YOUR_APP_NAME /usr/share/nginx/html
```

In your docker ignore file

```
.git

.firebase

.editorconfig

/node_modules

/e2e

/docs

.gitignore

*.zip

*.md

run
```

Build your container app

```
docker build -t YOUR_APP_NAME .
```

Run the app

```
docker run -d -it -p 80:80 YOUR_APP_NAME
```